# Does binding happen when posting with ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, post

Can you bind to an object when posting with jQuery?

You can call this controller action

```
 public ActionResult AddCar(Car myCar)
 {
   . . .
 }
```

Where the properties of the form using the binding of ASP.NET MVC to populate the properties of the car.

If I am posting via ajax and jQuery can I do the same thing?

Comment: Certainly you're aware that you can edit your original question. I mean you've asked 700+ here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an HTML form containing inputs to bind to the object:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/AddCar',
    data: $('#yourFormId').serialize(),
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

Or if you don't have a form and you want to bind the object properties manually:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/AddCar',
    data: { make: 'Peugeot', model: '407', year: '2009' },
    success: function(data) {
        alert('success');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.
You just need to make sure the keys in the form correspond to the Car object's properties.